# Using select box for displaying particular rows in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

i have three models desination,employe,branch.my asssociations are as follows

```
 class Employe < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :designation
   has_one :branch
 end

 class Designation < ActiveRecord::Base

 end
  class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :employe
  end
```

i have declared a select box in my employe form to select the designations from designation model.now i want  a select box in branch to display  employes with designation as managers .my branch form is

```
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :branch_address %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :branch_address ,class: "form-control"  
   ,placeholder: "Enter Branch Address"%>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :employe_id %><br>
   <%= f.select :employe_id,Employe.all.map{|e| [e.e_name,e.id]} %>
  </div><br>
```

here am getting list of all employes in my select box.bt i only  want  employes with designation as Manager.what to add in select box??plz help am new to rails

Comment: What is columns of `designation` table?

Comment: title is column in designation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

Write this def in employee model

```
class Employe < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.manager_list
     self.joins(:designation).where('designations.title = ?', 'manager').map{|e| [e.e_name,e.id]}
  end
end
```

Write this in your view

```
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :employe_id %><br>
 <%= f.select :employe_id,Employe.manager_list %>
</div>
```

Comment: its showing a blank select box,and plz also tell what code to put in index page

Comment: Thnaks bro ,it worked .....thank you very very much bhai..i was stucked from one 4 days in that

Comment: @aaquib Welcome :)